# Understand why WCF does not process all calls in parallel

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I am hosting a WCF application with multiples services. I am using .NET Framework 4.5 and IIS 8.5 (on Windows Server 2012 R2).

I have 8 VCPU and 16 gb of Ram.

I want to know why under load my calls are not processed in parallel.

Here a simple test I have made, on server side  :

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public  class Service1 : IService1
{
    Guid sessionGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

    public async Task<Guid> Ping()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

And I have set this for throttling :

```
<serviceThrottling 
        maxConcurrentCalls="350" maxConcurrentSessions="350" 
        maxConcurrentInstances="350" />
```

When I run 20 calls in parallel (using fiddler), I see that 10 calls are ended in 3 seconds and the others 10 calls are ended in 6 seconds. I have tried to modify `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` with no luck...

Could you please explain me how to process all 20 requests in 3 seconds in parallel?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain that you can get that degree of control - the OS will schedule the threads on the pool or within IIS, and the actual ordering of and execution of theses threads are, I expect, dependent on a number of factors that are not under the control of the program.   I could be wrong though.

Comment: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` will have 0 effect on IIS considering it will be IIS that is going to queue operations even before invoking your code

Comment: Tim, Micky : if I understand correctly what you are saying is that WCF is not able to give me real parallesation ? In my cas I will not be able to parallelize more than 10 calls concurrently ? it sounds weird... I have seen some recommandations to tweak ThreadPool.SetMinthreads : that's only in the cas I am hosting outside of IIS?